# Sql Delete Query Optimizations for Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need some help with optimizing following query.

> My Problem

I am trying to clean-up a table based on a **size** parameter. *(delete x Mb from this table)*. The way I thought implementing it is: iterate over the table, starting with the oldest entry, get each row size (I'm taking only blob columns into account), iterate over all linked tables and do the same operation for them; `if currentSize >= size` stop the query and return the list of `GUIDs` found

Please note that this is  part of a bigger query, so in the end I need the list of Ids.

> What I've tried

First, I tried writing it using `EntityFramework`, but its execution took too long and I was only halfway of finishing it. So I wrote it directly in `T-SQL`.

Below is what I managed to write. However, when running into over a SQL Azure Database, it throws a Timeout Exception. I know this is due to the DTU limitation, but I'm also wondering if this query can be improved. I am no SQL expert and I need your help.

> Current Query

```
DECLARE @maxSize int = 1
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE 
(
    Id uniqueidentifier,
    Size float,
    Position int
)
DECLARE @currentId uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @maxIterations int
DECLARE @index int = 1

SET @maxIterations = (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM WhereToDelete)


WHILE(@index < @maxIterations)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @tempTable
    SELECT MasterJobGUID,   ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn1),0) + 
                            ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn2),0) + 
                            ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn3),0) + 
                            ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn4),0),
            @index
    FROM WhereToDelete
    ORDER BY SomeColumn
    OFFSET @index ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

    SET @index=@index+1

    SET @currentid = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @tempTable ORDER BY Position DESC)

    UPDATE @tempTable
    SET Size = Size + ( SELECT SUM(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn),0))
                        FROM LinkedTable
                        WHERE ParentId = @currentId )

    UPDATE @tempTable
    SET Size = Size + ( SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(OtherBlobColumn),0)),0) 
                        FROM OtherLinkedTable
                        WHERE OtherLinkedTableId IN
                        (
                            SELECT OtherLinkedTableId FROM SomeTable
                            WHERE SomeTableId IN
                            (
                                SELECT SomeTableId FROM SomeOtherTable
                                WHERE ParentId = @currentId
                            )       
                        ))


    IF ((SELECT SUM(Size) FROM @tempTable) >= @maxSize*1000000)
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END
END

SELECT Id from @tempTable
```

Comment: Not sure but perhaps you could insert the sizes, guid and position in a table and perform a running sum order by position. No cursor required. You then select guids where running sum is less than the threshold.

Comment: @SalmanA I'm doing that. Or are you referring to something else? I guess it will take even longer if I go through all rows and then check their sizes

Comment: What is the actual error, because DTU limits don't cause query timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
SELECT MasterJobGUID FROM (
    SELECT [MasterJobGUID], SUM(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn1),0) + 
                                ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn2),0) + 
                                ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn3),0) + 
                                ISNULL(DATALENGTH(BlobColumn4),0)) 
                            OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) SizeTotal 
      FROM WhereToDelete) innerQuery 
 WHERE [SizeTotal] < @maxSize*1000000
```

That's using T-SQL windowing functions to return you the summed total size, and only returning the rows that match the criteria in a single operation. It should be a bunch more efficient than a cursor.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to update your query. The problem is, I have to take some other tables into account. For example, 1 row from Table A(WhereToDelete) has 10 rows in TableB, which has 100 rows in TableC.  If I use your query as it is, I will take only Table A into account.